# SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "lsnrctl st..." - rest of line ignored. error-17002

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to start oracle listener but I am getting error as below :

```
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "lsnrctl st..." - rest of line ignored.
error-17002
```

The connection has already started. I have tried with starting with 'user' command but failed in sqlPLUS.

What can be the cause of error?

[image]

[image: Screenshot of Error in sql developer]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LSNRCTL` is a command line-tool not a command on `SQL*PLUS`.

Try

`lsnrctl start listenername` on terminal OR `SQL> !lsnrctl status` on Linux and `SQL> host lsnrctl status listenername` on Windows.

Comment: from where I can get listenername?please help

Comment: Go to `ORACLE_HOME\network\admin` and find a file called `listener.ora`.

Comment: Thankx for help. I am able to start listener with command "host lsnrctl start" in sqlplus. But still root problem reamins the same i.e error 17002.

Comment: I think you are on Windows, can you make sure that the listener service is running ?

Comment: when I entered "host Isnrctl start" it showed that listner has already started line in sqlplus. Yes I am using Windows.

Comment: Then? It has started check the status as `lsnrctl status`? What next?

Comment: I got this....."Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully"

Comment: Please check the edit. I have added error screenshot in my recent edit.

Comment: Please create another question with details about the connection string used for that SQL Developer connection.